# How do I login to phpadmin on azure mysql in app

Tags: mysql, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to migrate a local MySQL database to azure MySQL In App, when I click on Manage in the MySQL in App pane on portal.azure.com it takes me to phpadmin login page displaying the username and password input form. How do I login to phpadmin  on azure MySQL in app as I'm not certain what credential to use to login.

Answer (score 0):

visit sitename.azurewebsites.net, then thereafter browse to sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpmyadmin, and it wont ask for a username and password. but ensure that you are login to portal.azure.com with your azure credentials.